# Derivation of formula for transformer maximum power

Tags: power, transformer, converter, ferrite

How can I derive the formula for the maximum power handling of a HF transformer with ferrite core utilized in a selected converter topology (push-pull for me). The formulas I have seen so far utilize:

\$A_c\$: Cross section or effective area of the core
\$A_w\$: Window area where the wires are wound

And from these the usual power formula uses the area product \$A_P = A_C*A_W\$ together
with topology factors and winding factors...

I understand that copper losses play an important role regarding heating up and too high
temperatures decreases the permeability \$\mu_r\$ or makes it non-magnetic. However, what is the right ansatz for finding such a power formula?

Up to now I wanted to multiply primary voltage \$U_1\$ with maximum current and somehow
derive maximum current from the maximum unsaturating \$B\$-field, giving me something like

\$I_{max}=j_{max}*A_w\$ 
\$U_1 = \frac{d\Phi}{dt} \approx A_c*B_{max} f \$

For a given transformer geometry I have with \$A_c = 368 \$mm^2, and for \$0.15\$ mT I get a few Watts... (\$ 5 A/mm^2 \$, \$A_c \approx A_w\$)

Which means, that the ansatz for this formula is more like power dissipation and not
maximum power handling... or complete garbage. What am I thinking wrong?

I just cannot find any derivation of any of the empirical formulas like

\$P_o = \frac{A_P * k_{topology} * B_{max} * f}{D_{cma}}\$

where mine would lead to

\$P_o = A_P * B_{max} * f * j_{max}\$ with \$D_{cma} = 1/j_{max}\$

which is orders of magnitude off because of missing \$k_{topology}\$. And also a missing
\$N\$ I neglected because of actually \$U = N*\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ which makes it even
more unclear...

Please help :)